# Celery + Django best practice

Tags: django, celery

I have been reading about the `celery` and `django` in these posts ([here](http://django.zone/blog/posts/background-jobs-django-and-celery/) and [here](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/02/how-to-install-celery-on-django-and.html)), and all the logic/tasks works in the `celery.py`, but in the official documentation they separated in two files: `celery.py` and `tasks.py`. So which is the best practice? This affects the performance?

Comment: I have published an article on writing scalable Django apps and it also includes celery best practices. https://digiqt.com/blog/django-best-practices-for-scalable-apps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the tasks shouldn't have any noticeable affect on performance. The suggestion to use a separate tasks.py is for better organization.

From [the Celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html):

> Note that this example project layout [a separate tasks.py for each app] is suitable for larger projects, for simple projects you may use a single contained module that defines both the app and tasks, like in the First Steps with Celery tutorial.